# filter lines based on some criteria

Tags: text-processing, command-line, bioinformatics

I have some `.vcf` files and I want to filter some variants out. This is just small part of my file: there are some header lines at the beginning of the file (starting with ##) and then variants (one row per variant).

```
##fileformat=VCFv4.2
##source=combiSV-v2.2
##fileDate=Mon May  8 11:32:53 2023
##contig=<ID=chrM,length=16571>
##contig=<ID=chr1,length=249250621>    
##INFO=<ID=END,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="End position of the variant described in this record">
##INFO=<ID=SVCALLERS,Number=.,Type=String,Description="SV callers that support this SV">
##FORMAT=<ID=GT,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Genotype">
##FORMAT=<ID=DR,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="# High-quality reference reads">
##FORMAT=<ID=DV,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="# High-quality variant reads">
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  Sample
1   10862   id.1    N   <INS>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=INS;SVLEN=101;END=10862;SVCALLERS=cutesv,SVIM    GT:DR:DV    1/1:0:26
1   90258   id.2    N   <INS>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=INS;SVLEN=118;END=90258;SVCALLERS=SVIM,NanoSV    GT:DR:DV    1/1:0:9
1   90259   id.3    N   <INS>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=INS;SVLEN=36;END=90259;SVCALLERS=Sniffles    GT:DR:DV    0/1:44:7
1   185824  id.4    N   <DEL>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=DEL;SVLEN=80;END=186660;SVCALLERS=Sniffles,cutesv    GT:DR:DV    1/1:0:15
1   186241  id.5    N   <DEL>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=DEL;SVLEN=418;END=186662;SVCALLERS=SVIM,NanoSV   GT:DR:DV    1/1:2:12
1   526111  id.6    N   <DEL>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=DEL;SVLEN=624;END=526735;SVCALLERS=Sniffles,cutesv   GT:DR:DV    0/1:8
2   91926078    id.3958 N   <BND>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=BND;SVLEN=.;END=;SVCALLERS=Sniffles,NanoSV   GT:DR:DV    0/1:60:15
```

While keeping the header lines, I want to remove rows with `SVLEN` < 100 and those with only one `SVCALLERS` included. These are two criteria that both must be met, in other words I want to keep only rows with `SVLEN` > 100 and at least two `SVCALLERS`).

In addition there are some rows where `ALT` is `BND` and the file does not provide any `SVLEN` for this type of variant, so if the row contains `BND`, I just want to keep it if it is supported by two callers.

Examples: I want to drop this variant because `SVLEN` is less than 100 and only one `SVCALLERS` detected it:

```
SVTYPE=INS;SVLEN=36;END=90259;SVCALLERS=Sniffles    GT:DR:DV    0/1:44:7
1   185824  id.4    N   <DEL>   .   PASS
```

Or this row as well, although there are two callers but SVLEN is less than 100:

```
SVTYPE=DEL;SVLEN=80;END=186660;SVCALLERS=Sniffles,cutesv    GT:DR:DV    1/1:0:15
1   186241  id.5    N   <DEL>   .   PASS
```

Is there an easy way to do it? Thanks

My final file should look like this:

```
##fileformat=VCFv4.2
##source=combiSV-v2.2
##fileDate=Mon May  8 11:32:53 2023
##contig=<ID=chrM,length=16571>
##contig=<ID=chr1,length=249250621>    
##INFO=<ID=END,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="End position of the variant described in this record">
##INFO=<ID=SVCALLERS,Number=.,Type=String,Description="SV callers that support this SV">
##FORMAT=<ID=GT,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Genotype">
##FORMAT=<ID=DR,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="# High-quality reference reads">
##FORMAT=<ID=DV,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="# High-quality variant reads">
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  Sample
1   10862   id.1    N   <INS>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=INS;SVLEN=101;END=10862;SVCALLERS=cutesv,SVIM    GT:DR:DV    1/1:0:26
1   90258   id.2    N   <INS>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=INS;SVLEN=118;END=90258;SVCALLERS=SVIM,NanoSV    GT:DR:DV    1/1:0:9
1   186241  id.5    N   <DEL>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=DEL;SVLEN=418;END=186662;SVCALLERS=SVIM,NanoSV   GT:DR:DV    1/1:2:12
1   526111  id.6    N   <DEL>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=DEL;SVLEN=624;END=526735;SVCALLERS=Sniffles,cutesv   GT:DR:DV    0/1:8
2   91926078    id.3958 N   <BND>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=BND;SVLEN=.;END=;SVCALLERS=Sniffles,NanoSV   GT:DR:DV    0/1:60:15
```

Comment: hey, since you're already settled on `awk`: Do you have an existing approach that you've already worked on and are stuck at?

Comment: Hey, not necessarily, I am just trying to find a way and I thought awk can be a way to achieve it

Comment: That's a LOT of requirements/checks to be asking for help with. Why not ask for help with a couple of checks and then try adding on to it to implement the rest yourself? Right now it's like you're asking someone to develop your whole project for free.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a perl way:

```
$ perl -F'\t' -lane '
  if(/^#/){ print; next }; 
  $F[7] =~ /\bSVLEN=(\d+)/; 
  $svlen=$1; 
  $F[7] =~ /\bSVCALLERS=([^;]+)/; 
  @callers=split(/,/,$1); 
  print if $svlen > 100 && scalar(@callers) > 1' file.vcf 
##fileformat=VCFv4.2
##source=combiSV-v2.2
##fileDate=Mon May  8 11:32:53 2023
##contig=<ID=chrM,length=16571>
##contig=<ID=chr1,length=249250621>    
##INFO=<ID=END,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="End position of the variant described in this record">
##INFO=<ID=SVCALLERS,Number=.,Type=String,Description="SV callers that support this SV">
##FORMAT=<ID=GT,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Genotype">
##FORMAT=<ID=DR,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="# High-quality reference reads">
##FORMAT=<ID=DV,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="# High-quality variant reads">
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  Sample
1   10862   id.1    N   <INS>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=INS;SVLEN=101;END=10862;SVCALLERS=cutesv,SVIM    GT:DR:DV    1/1:0:26
1   90258   id.2    N   <INS>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=INS;SVLEN=118;END=90258;SVCALLERS=SVIM,NanoSV    GT:DR:DV    1/1:0:9
1   186241  id.5    N   <DEL>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=DEL;SVLEN=418;END=186662;SVCALLERS=SVIM,NanoSV   GT:DR:DV    1/1:2:12
1   526111  id.6    N   <DEL>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=DEL;SVLEN=624;END=526735;SVCALLERS=Sniffles,cutesv   GT:DR:DV    0/1:8
```

#### Explanation

- `perl -F'\t' -lane`: the `-a` makes perl work kinda like `awk` in that it automatically splits each input line on the character given by `-F` (whitespace, by default, like awk) and saves it in the array `@F`. So, since arrays start counting at `0`, the first field is `$F[0[`, the second `$F[1]` and so on. Next, the `-l` removes trailing newlines from each input line, and also adds a `\n` to each `print` call, the `-n` means "read the input file line by line and apply the script given by `-e` to each line.
- `if(/^#/){ print; next };` : if this is a header line, just print it and move on to the next line.
- `$F[7] =~ /\bSVLEN=(\d+)/; $svlen=$1;`: match the longest string of numbers after `SVLEN=` in the 8th field and save it as `$svlen`. This will be the length.  The `\b` ensures we only match at word boundaries so this won't fail if you have something like `NOTSVLEN=` in your file.
- `$F[7] =~ /\bSVCALLERS=([^;]+)/; @callers=split(/,/,$1);`: now search the 8th field for the string `SVCALLERS=`, take the longest stretch of non-`;` characters after it, and then split that on `,` into the array `@callers`. This now has the list of CNV callers used for this CNV.
- `print if $svlen > 100 && scalar(@callers) > 1`: we now print the line if the length was more than 100 and the number of callers (`scalar(@array)` gives the number of elements in an array) is more than `1`.

And here's the same basic thing in a more concise and less clear way if you prefer your commands mildly golfed:

```
perl -F'\t' -lane '$F[7]=~/\bSVLEN=(\d+)/;$s=$1;$F[7]=~/\bSVCALLERS=([^;]+)/; /^#/ || ($s>100&&scalar(split(/,/,$1)) > 1) || next; print' file.vcf
```

---

If you also want to keep lines with no SVLEN as long as they have at least two callers, use this:

```
$ perl -F'\t' -lane 'if(/^#/){ print; next }; $F[7] =~ /\bSVLEN=([.\d]+)/; $svlen=$1; $F[7] =~ /\bSVCALLERS=([^;]+)/; next unless ($svlen > 100 || $svlen == ".") && scalar(split(/,/,$1)) > 1; print' file.vcf 
##fileformat=VCFv4.2
##source=combiSV-v2.2
##fileDate=Mon  May 8   11:32:53    2023
##contig=<ID=chrM,length=16571>
##contig=<ID=chr1,length=249250621> 
##INFO=<ID=END,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="End   position    of  the variant described   in  this    record">
##INFO=<ID=SVCALLERS,Number=.,Type=String,Description="SV   callers that    support this    SV">
##FORMAT=<ID=GT,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Genotype">
##FORMAT=<ID=DR,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="#    High-quality    reference   reads">
##FORMAT=<ID=DV,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="#    High-quality    variant reads">
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  Sample
1   10862   id.1    N   <INS>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=INS;SVLEN=101;END=10862;SVCALLERS=cutesv,SVIM    GT:DR:DV    1/1:0:26
1   90258   id.2    N   <INS>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=INS;SVLEN=118;END=90258;SVCALLERS=SVIM,NanoSV    GT:DR:DV    1/1:0:9
1   186241  id.5    N   <DEL>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=DEL;SVLEN=418;END=186662;SVCALLERS=SVIM,NanoSV   GT:DR:DV    1/1:2:12
1   526111  id.6    N   <DEL>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=DEL;SVLEN=624;END=526735;SVCALLERS=Sniffles,cutesv   GT:DR:DV0/1:8
2   91926078    id.3958 N   <BND>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=BND;SVLEN=.;END=;SVCALLERS=Sniffles,NanoSV   GT:DR:DV0/1:60:15
```

Comment: Hey@terdon, nice this indeed does what I want. However I noticed I have some rows which are translocations and the vcf file does not provide ant SVLEN. (they are shown as: SVLEN=.). So if I face with such a variant I just need to meet the second criteria; variant confirmed by two caller. Is there any way to adjust it in your code? I just updated my question based on this. Sorry about that, totally forgot about it

Comment: @Anna1364 see update. Note that structural variant VCF files can also have  `<CNV>` in the ALT field, and some other values, I think, they can be imprecise in which case they will have no length, and various other issues.

Answer (score 1):

This ignores the header lines, just handles the data lines.

```
start cmd:> awk -F '=|;| +' '$11<100 || $15 !~ "," { next; }; { print $0; }' input
1   10862   id.1    N   <INS>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=INS;SVLEN=101;END=10862;SVCALLERS=cutesv,SVIM    GT:DR:DV    1/1:0:26
1   90258   id.2    N   <INS>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=INS;SVLEN=118;END=90258;SVCALLERS=SVIM,NanoSV    GT:DR:DV    1/1:0:9
1   186241  id.5    N   <DEL>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=DEL;SVLEN=418;END=186662;SVCALLERS=SVIM,NanoSV   GT:DR:DV    1/1:2:12
1   526111  id.6    N   <DEL>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=DEL;SVLEN=624;END=526735;SVCALLERS=Sniffles,cutesv   GT:DR:DV    0/1:8
```

## Update 1

For the adjusted question

```
start cmd:> awk -F '=|;| +' '/^#/ { print; next; }; $5 != "<BND>" && $11<100 || $15 !~ "," { next; }; $5 == "<BND>" && $15 !~ "," { next; }; { print $0; }' input
##fileformat=VCFv4.2
##source=combiSV-v2.2
##fileDate=Mon May  8 11:32:53 2023
##contig=<ID=chrM,length=16571>
##contig=<ID=chr1,length=249250621>
##INFO=<ID=END,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="End position of the variant described in this record">
##INFO=<ID=SVCALLERS,Number=.,Type=String,Description="SV callers that support this SV">
##FORMAT=<ID=GT,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Genotype">
##FORMAT=<ID=DR,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="# High-quality reference reads">
##FORMAT=<ID=DV,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="# High-quality variant reads">
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  Sample
1   10862   id.1    N   <INS>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=INS;SVLEN=101;END=10862;SVCALLERS=cutesv,SVIM    GT:DR:DV    1/1:0:26
1   90258   id.2    N   <INS>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=INS;SVLEN=118;END=90258;SVCALLERS=SVIM,NanoSV    GT:DR:DV    1/1:0:9
1   186241  id.5    N   <DEL>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=DEL;SVLEN=418;END=186662;SVCALLERS=SVIM,NanoSV   GT:DR:DV    1/1:2:12
1   526111  id.6    N   <DEL>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=DEL;SVLEN=624;END=526735;SVCALLERS=Sniffles,cutesv   GT:DR:DV    0/1:8
2   91926078    id.3958 N   <BND>   .   PASS    SVTYPE=BND;SVLEN=.;END=;SVCALLERS=Sniffles,NanoSV   GT:DR:DV    0/1:60:15
```

Comment: I slightly updated my question, there was one missing point. Also I need to keep the headers.

Comment: @Anna1364 See the update

Comment: Thank so much for proving your answer as well, that also worked.